# Не работают align, justify-content, margin и т.д

Tags: php, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно сделать так чтобы элемент div поднялся, если дать отрицательный отступ то нечего не происходит

```css
<head>
    <style>
        div{
            margin-top: -200px;
            height: 630px;
            width: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        body{
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        img{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 150px 0 0 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($_GET['id']!=null){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $idresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id='$id'");
    while($ri = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresult)){
        echo '<img src="'.$ri['image'].'">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<h1>';
        echo $ri['name'];
        echo '</h1>';
        echo $ri['description'];
        echo '<p>';
        echo $ri['price'];
        echo '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что div выводится, но из-за `margin-top: -200px` он уходит за область вьюпорта.. Как бы это логично.

Comment: Хм.. Ну значит условие не выполняется. @DVD_AM, попробуйте дописать `if($_GET['id']!=null){/*ТУТ ваш код что в примере*/} else echo "условие не работает";`

Comment: Тогда проверьте запрос в БД и существует ли в БД строка с таким IDом

Comment: https://ibb.co/fGh5QYr

Answer (score 0):

```
    div{
        position: relative;
        top:-200px;
        height: 630px;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

А в других тегах надо добавить display:block;

```
body{
    display:block;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    display:block;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 150px 0 0 70px;
}
```

p.s почему бы тебе не использовать только одно echo ?В колонку же сложно